# object based on another object in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2

Передо мной стоит задача создать объект А на основе объекта В. сейчас я делаю это так:

```
//$b - это объект класса B с определенным набором аттрибутов
$a = new A();
$a->setParam1( $b->getParam1() );
$a->setParam2( $b->getParam2() );
...
$a->setParamN( $b->getParamN() );

$a->setSomeAnotherParam( $somevalue );// определяем еще аттрибуты, которых нет в Б
...
```

Но мне не нравится это решения. Как можно сделать лучше?

P.S. Это посто копирование данных из одного объекта в другой. Ничего усложнять не надо. И, конечно, у меня были причины создавать два разных класса =)
Есть идеи?

P.P.S. Кстати, это мой первый симфони проект. Могу не знать элементарных вещей. Не судите строго)

Comment: Статический конструктор вам в помощь

Comment: Ну и вопрос не имеет отношения к symfony. Совсем.

Comment: да. я просто надеялся, что в симфони есть что-то готовое на этот случай.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том, что вы создаете один объект из другого нет ничего страшного и предосудительного. Распространенной практикой в данном случае является создание отдельного статического метода, который использовался бы вместо конструктора.

Например так:

```
class A
{
    public function getFoo() {}
    public function getBar() {}
    public function getBaz() {}
}

class B
{
    public static function createFromA(A $a)
    {
        $instance = new B();
        $instance->setFoo($a->getFoo());
        $instance->setBar($a->getBar());
        $instance->setBaz($a->getBaz());

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

А вот и пример использования:

```
$a = new A();
$b = B::createFromA($a);
```

Аналогичный подход используется, например, в методе [`\DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetimeimmutable.createfrommutable.php)

Данный подход позволяет вам с одной стороны собрать всю логику переноса свойств в одном месте, а с другой делает ваш код максимально выразительным.

Comment: во! за это спасибо. Что-то подобное мне и было нужно)

Comment: @MaxRudchenko, Если я полностью ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте ответ как "принятый" (галка слева от ответа). Это поможет другим участникам понять что вопрос уже решен, а ответ может быть использован в сходных ситуациях